# Self invoking function breaks when trigger twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML blocks that should be converted to `iframe` elements. One is for mobile and the other one is not. The mobile element is hidden for Desktop via the class `screen-desktop-hidden`.

I have a self invoking function that when the page is load triggers the creation of the iframe getting the attributes from the HTML blocks and replacing them with the `iframe` elements. However, these break when both the elements are triggered by the self invoking function.

```
import 'main';

(function() {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Google Static Map
   */
  (element => {
    // Selected element is passed to this self-instantiating function
    if (element) {
      console.dir(element.attributes.class.value)
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.setAttribute('src', element.dataset.googleStaticMap);
        iframe.setAttribute('class', element.attributes.class.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('width', element.attributes.width.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('height', element.attributes.height.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder',
                              element.attributes.frameborder.value);

        element.replaceWith(iframe);
      });
    }
  })(document.querySelector('[data-js="google-static-map"]'));
})();
```

Notice how the query selector is pass `[data-js="google-static-map"]` as a parameter. These is coming from two blocks which I'm guessing is where the error is coming from. So this mean it needs to be unique?

Here is the blocks that are set to be triggered by the Self Invoking Function

```
  <section>
      <div data-js="google-static-map"
           data-google-static-map="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?&center={{ post.address.lat}},{{ post.address.lng }}&q={{ post.address.address|url_encode }}&key={{ function('constant', 'GOOGLE_MAPS_EMBED') }}&zoom=15"
           class="block bg-blue-light border border-grey-light print:hidden screen-desktop:hidden"
           width="100%"
           height="300" 
           frameborder="0"></div>
    </section>
    
    {{ cspr_iframes_nonce }}
    
    <section class="wrap screen-desktop:layout-sidebar-gutter">
      <aside class="hidden screen-desktop:block">
         <div data-js="google-static-map"
              data-google-static-map="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?&center={{ post.address.lat}},{{ post.address.lng }}&q={{ post.address.address|url_encode }}&key={{ function('constant', 'GOOGLE_MAPS_EMBED') }}&zoom=15" class="block bg-blue-light border border-grey-light print:hidden"
              width="100%"
              height="496"
              frameborder="0"></div>
```

Notice how both `div` elements have `data-js="google-static-map"` the data attribute that is used by the self invoking function to trigger the creation of the iframe element. Does this mean the data-js attribute has to be unique? How can I go about having the Self Invoking Function triggered for both `div` elements?

Comment: *How* does this break? Do you get an error? Do you get something you don't expect?

Comment: `document.querySelector('[data-js="google-static-map"]')` will always only get you the **first match** to the CSS-selector. If you want to do something with *both* you should use `document.querySelectorAll(...)` instead. But of course, your function will then have to deal with a collection of DOM nodes.

Comment: @VLAZ it just doesn't show the map, If I comment one of the two divs out the map is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  (collection => {
    // collection of selected elements is passed to this immediately invoked function
    for (let i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
      let element=collection[i];
      console.dir(element.attributes.class.value)
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.setAttribute('src', element.dataset.googleStaticMap);
        iframe.setAttribute('class', element.attributes.class.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('width', element.attributes.width.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('height', element.attributes.height.value);
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder',
                              element.attributes.frameborder.value);

        element.replaceWith(iframe);
      });
    }
  })(document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="google-static-map"]'));
})();
```

This is of course still incomplete as there is no HTML markup to work on.